# PHP Fetch Name and Value FROM $_GET

Tags: php, foreach, get, key-value

I'm trying to convert a simple if/elseif conditional to a case conditional and only a single $_GET value is being passed at a time via an img src link so is the foreach loop necessary and/or does the case conditional actually need to be inside the loop? Otherwise how to I retrieve the key name and value from the $_GET?

```
if (isset($_GET)) :
    foreach ($_GET as $GETkey=>$GETvalue):
        switch ($GETkey):
            case "AuthorID":
                $Year = date("Y");
                $AuthorName = DBLookup("SELECT `AuthorName` FROM authorbiographies WHERE `ID`=$GETvalue",$siteDB);
                $String = "Copyright &copy; $Year\n$AuthorName";
                $FontSize = 10;
                $Angle = 0;
            break;
            case "CategoryID":
                $String = DBLookup("SELECT `CategoryName` FROM categories WHERE `ID`=$GETvalue",$siteDB);
                $FontSize = 15;
                $Angle = 0;
            break;
            case "Splash":
                $String = urldecode($GETvalue);
                $FontSize = 38;
                $Angle = 0;
            break;
        endswitch;
    endforeach;
endif;
```

It is being called using:

```
 <img src="/internals/viewers/show_logo.php?AuthorID=1">
```

or

```
 <img src="/internals/viewers/show_logo.php?CategoryID=1">
```

for example.

Comment: The code should work, although it's not the best way to write it.

Comment: Use `if (isset($_GET['AuthorID'])) ...`

Comment: What does `var_dump($_GET);` show?

Comment: You shouldn't need to call `urldecode()`. PHP does it automatically when filling in `$_GET`.

Comment: I was using $_GET['AuthorID'] in the original if/else but with the case conditional, I don't know in advance which GET it is so it needs to also fetch the name dynamically and that is the point of the question. For var_dump($_GET), it seems to have no output but difficult to tell as this code generates an image with headers. I have diagnostic code in the site's footer and var_dump($_GET") fetches nothing there. As for urldecode, that's a detail and not an issue here but thank you for the comment.

Comment: If `var_dump($_GET)` isn't printing anything then something is removing the URL parameters. The problem isn't this part of the script.

Comment: You don't need to know in advance, that's why you use `if(isset())` to tell which one it is.

Comment: One thing I noticed recently with Firefox that whenever any page loads, the GET parameters are replaced by =reload even if I haven't reloaded the page. I'm not sure where those are coming from but if I do reload the page with =reload in the address bar, then var_dump($_GET) shows it.

Comment: @Barmar My code is using the name of the $_GET to know which part of the case to use. If I have to use if(isset()) on each by name, then I might as well go back to my original if/elseif which did exactly that but I prefer to use case. I am open to other ways to do it, though.

Comment: Sounds like a redirect, maybe in the server configuration.

Comment: They're equivalent, either should work. The loop makes it seem like there can be multiple options and you want to do each of them. `if/elif/elif/...` makes it clear that they're mutually exclusive.

Comment: The =reload seemed to appear out of nowhere recently and I can't tell where it's coming from and the AskUbuntu forum didn't help.

Comment: I doubt it's anything automatic, it must be coming from your server or script.

Comment: It’s not coming from my script but possibly from Apache as it seemed to start when I re-installed it. I’ve searched through the conf files but see nothing to account for it so any clues would be most welcome!

Comment: Sorry, but there's nothing in the question that provides any clue to this.

Comment: So back to my question and presuming that my code is valid, should my conditional be inside or after the close of the foreach - or does it even need a foreach? If after, what should I use to fetch the name and value of the $_GET?

Comment: Your code is fine. The problem is the data is missing.

Comment: Yes, I see that but that problem aside, my question is whether or not the case conditional needs to be within the foreach loop or after it, or is there another way to retrieve both the $_GET key and value?

Comment: Of course it has to be within the foreach loop, that's where the variables are set. Your code is fine, I've said it multiple times.

Comment: I've agreed multiple times that it is correct as you stated and that's not what I am asking. I am not sure why "of course" the conditional needs to be inside the loop as it is fetching only a single value. The values would need to be created inside the loop but does the conditional itself need to be there too? Once the key and value of been defined and assigned a variable, only a single conditional case needs to be met but, so that I can understand it, can you please explain why it also needs to be inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `key()` and `current()` functions to get the current key and value of an array.

For an array with a single element, this will return the first and only key and value. There's no need for a loop.

```
$GETkey = key($_GET);
$GETvalue = current($_GET);
switch ($GETkey) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That works perfectly and was exactly what I needed to know. The $_GET is working now too for some reason.